# getting actual type of generic type <T,S>

Tags: java, generics, javafx

I am supposed to create a new Object that extends the functionality of a TableView in JavaFX (lets call it TableViewPlus - I dont have a better name yet lol). One new functionality is supposed to be a filter for each TableColumn, dependent of the type in the column.

For example: I have Objects of type "Person", which contains a field for a name (String), a date of birth (LocalDate) and an ID (Integer). These were defined outside of my TableViewPlus and just passed to it using the following method:

```
public void addColumns(TableColumn<T, ?>... columns) {
    table.getColumns().addAll(columns);
}
```

Later on, I want to add filters to each table (as a contextmenu). For the name column I would need a filter with simple string matching, for the date column I would need one with a datepicker in it, and so on... Now here is the problem: How do I tell what datatype is in my column? (How do I tell of which type '?' is?).

My solution is the following, which only works when there is data already in the table:

```
private void createFilters() {
    for (TableColumn<T,?> col : table.getColumns()) {
        if (col.getCellData(0).getClass().equals(String.class) {
            //create string filter
        } else if (col.getCellData(0).getClass().equals(Integer.class) {
            //create int filter
        } else if (col.getCellData(0).getClass().equals(LocalDate.class) {
            //create date filter
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this sucks! :D

---

If it is not directly possible with the given stuff, another possible solution might be to create the filter directly with the columns. So I would not let TableColumns be passed to my TableViewPlus, just a name and a callback, like so:

```
public <S> void test(String name, Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<T,S>,ObservableValue<S>> value) {
    TableColumn<T,S> col = new TableColumn(name);
    col.setCellValueFactory(value);
    table.getColumns().add(col);
    //if (S == String.class) {} //this line does not work because "Cannot find Symbol: variable S"
}
```

This method works so far that the column is correctly created and filled with data (so S is somehow set correctly) and I get the same results from the createFilters() method above, but this just uses the first item in the table again. How do I get the class of S?

Comment: Ever heard of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)?

Comment: Indeed I have^^. But surely there must we a way to get the actual runtime class of S for each column without accessing the data of the table

Comment: Maybe you have read it, but obviously you didn't understand it. Type erasure simply means that the actual type argument used in instances of a generic type is _erased_ and thus cannot be retrieved. At runtime there is no information about it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
private final Map<TableColumn<T,?>, Class<?>> columnTypes = new HashMap<>();

public <S> void addColumn(TableColumn<T,S> col, Class<S> type) {
    getColumns().add(col) ;
    columnTypes.put(col, type);
}
```

Now you can retrieve the type of the column when you need it, and do something along the lines of

```
if (columnTypes.get(col) == String.class) {
    // create String filter...
}
```

etc

It's not pretty, but it's better than assuming all tables have data and the data is all the same type.

Comment: So someone who uses my TableViewPlus would have to call this method like so:

...addColumn(new TableColumn<Person, String>, String.class);

right?

Comment: As Seelenvirtuose hints at, though, you might consider other design options. E.g. consider a method along the lines of `public <S, E extends Node> void addFilterEditor(TableColumn<T,S> column, E filterEditor, BiPredicate<S, E> filter)` which takes a column, a node to use as the editor for the filter for that column, and a function taking the cell value, the editor and returning a boolean representing whether or not the value passes the filter. Then provide some "standard" editors for known types.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is called a *[type token](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html)*. Pass a type token to the constructor of your class, if you want to access that type independently.

Here is a simplified example that you can easily work into your own classes:

```
public class Generified<T> {
    private T value;
    private Class<T> typeToken;

    public Generified(Class<T> typeToken) { this.typeToken = typeToken; }
    public T get() { return value; }
    public void set(T value) { this.value = value; }
    public void someMethod() { System.out.println(typeToken.getName()); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generified<Integer> generified = new Generified<>(Integer.class);
        generified.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Running this program will produce the output

> java.lang.Integer

Note that you still have type safety. The following code - for example - will not compile:

```
Generified<Integer> generified = new Generified<>(String.class);
```

Comment: So I would have to create a custom TableColumn class?

Comment: I fear that you need to redesign your program. Usually it should not be necessary to access the type and switch on it. Maybe you can create specialized subclasses of TableColumn that do not need to be generic anymore. This is far beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. In Java, generics are only present *at compile time*. As soon as the code is compiled, every type parameter basically becomes an `Object` reference. So at rumtime it not possible anymore to find out what the type parameters of a generic type are. This is called type erasure. This was necessary for newer Java versions to be backward-compatible.

One solution for you is explicitly store the type of the contents somewhere. `Class` is a normal class in Java, and so in particular you can have fields of this type.

Comment: But even if all my generics are converted to Object, it should still be possible to check if a certain Object to a given column is of type String or Integer or whatever, right?

Comment: Just a little but important side note: The parameter type will be compiled to the bound or to `Object` if it has none. So for the example declaration `class MyBox<T extends Number>` the `type is `Number` and not `Object`.

Comment: @user2336377 You can always retrieve the actual class object of any object with `myObject.getClass()` but this is a completely other story. You are talking about the type parameters of a generic type. I will tell you another solution.

Comment: Well the problem with getClass() is that it cannot really be applied in this context... If I called this method on the column then I would just get TableColumn returned, which is not what I want. I want the class of the objects that the column holds.